# Can you use ports or markets after playing all action disks?

Tags: archipelago

In Archipelago, say you have already played all your action discs, but for an arbitrary reason you did not use your ports or markets. Does this means you cannot use them anymore in this action phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I might've misunderstood [the rules](http://download.ludically.com/ArchipelagoSite/Archipelago.Rulebook.EN.web.pdf). The correct answer, I think, is **you can't**!

In page 8, you read:

> [...]each player plays one round by placing one of his action discs (AD) on the action wheel and performing the corresponding action. Players continue playing rounds until all players have used up their action discs or cannot play anything; then they proceed to phase 6.

The concept of *round* is important here. A player has a round "until all players have used up their action disks or cannot play anything".

In page 12, you read:

> Each player can use one port or market during each of his rounds.

This means that you can only use market or ports once per round if you have a round. Therefore, you can't use them after your action disks have finished.

Likewise, this is extensible to evolution cards (page 14):

> Each player can use one evolution card during each of his rounds.

Comment: You can edit or delete your answers at any time; it's usually better to edit your answer than to create a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I decided to write another post because the truth is I'm still interpreting what I read and I believe there is still the possibility that I'm wrong. So I thought I should let people vote (if they wish to do that) in the answer they agree with.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the ports or markets if you have no action disks left to play.

The easy way to think about this is:

On your turn:

- **Place one of your action disks on the board and take that action**
- *(Before or After you place your action disk)*

  - **Use one Evolution card** (optional)
- *(Before or After you place your action disk)*

  - **Pay one coin to use a port or a market** (optional)
  - You can use each market or port you own once per round, and only one per turn.

So if you don't have any action markers, you won't be able to use a port/market.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer to that in the manual, page 8.

> Players continue playing rounds until all players have used up their action discs or cannot play anything; then they proceed to phase 6.

So, yes, you can still use a market or port, if you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

The rules only state:

> Starting with the first player, and continuing in the order of play,
> each player plays one round by placing one of his action discs (AD) on
> the action wheel and performing the corresponding action. Players continue
> playing rounds until all players have used up their action discs or cannot play
> anything; then they proceed to phase 6.

These rules are frustratingly incomplete. The phase ends when everyone has "used up their action discs or cannot play anything" but doesn't particularly explain what happens when only some players have used up their action discs. Since rounds continue until everyone is in this position, you will very often have situations where plays have no AD but their turn comes up.

The rules are ill-defined as to how this all too common situation should be handled. Any argument for either side will become increasingly more convulsed and lead to more questions when attempting to explain the way the game plays, for example trying to reconcile the idea that you have to play an action for you to be "having a round" but you can play evolution cards "on your round" that could use up all your AD and prevent you from "having a round".